# Not sure how to test this properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I have a route that matches:

```
get 'beat' => 'heartbeat#beat', as: => 'beat'
#=> api_v1_beat GET  /api/v1/beat(.:format)   api/v1/heartbeat#beat
```

I then have a controller, exceptionally basic!

```
module Api
  module V1
    class HeartBeatController < BaseController

      def beat
        respond json: {}, status: 200
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Concept is you would ping this every 15-30 seconds to see if were alive.

Now I need a test for this,

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::HeartBeatController do
  context "200" do
    it "should ping the  heartbeat and return 200" do
      get :beat
      expect(response.code).to eql '200'
    end
  end
end
```

But it fails:

```
 Failure/Error: get :beat
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"beat", :controller=>"api/v1/heart_beat"}
```

uh ??? Its pretty obvious what it states, but maybe I am missing something so rudimentary and basic?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 or Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
get 'beat' => 'heart_beat#beat', as: => 'beat'
```

Note for others:
In Rails 4, the name of the controller object in a route must be in snake_case for multiple word controllers.

```
Ex:
get 'action' => 'snake_case_controller_name#action'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a routing test also:

```
describe HeartBeatController do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #beat" do
      get("/beat}").should route_to("api/v1/heart_beat#beat")
    end
  end
end
```